# Are directTV dishes energized in some way?

Tags: grounding, tv-antenna

Are directTV dishes usually energized in some way?

I was recently at my grandmothers house installing an over the air digital tv antenna. I decided to use the same coax cable that originally ran to her directTV dish.

I first unplugged the DirecTV receiver then checked other rooms in the house for receivers.

I then looked around for where the coax plugs entered the house.  The installer had drilled through the walls in each room and run the cable on the outside.

When I climbed the ladder to remove the old dish I was mildly, but quite irritatingly, shocked.  Any time i put my hand back on the bolt I continued to receive this mild shock.

I then went inside the house and turned off the main breaker.  Came back out and absolutely no shock.

Is this a symptom of a grounding problem of some type?  I have touched a live 120V lead before, and it was a SIGNIFICANTLY worse shock.

Any ideas?  Also let me know if this question should be retitled.

Comment: Just an interesting fact: I once spliced to coax cables together for DirecTV and it did not work as the splitter I used to splice it did not carry the current over.  A barrel connector solved the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, satellite dishes are frequently powered by DC current over the coax connection. The DC power comes from a "line power inserter" which will attach somewhere to the coax before it reaches the TV's. It may be a single connection or a splitter as well, but either design will connect to an outlet.

[image]

Edit: As others have mentioned in the comments below, the injector may also be built into your set top box.

Comment: Depending on your DirecTV setup, the power may be provided by the receiver or a SWM switch.   Most DTV dishes "see" multiple satellites; different DC voltages and polarities are used to select which satellite is currently being tuned.  SWM systems used a digital signal over the coax to provide this function with a constant DC signal.

Comment: Alternatively, the injector may be integrated into the set top box.  The units used by Shaw Direct (formerly Starchoice) in Canada work like this.

Answer (score 2):

Most satellite dishes have something called an [LNB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-noise_block_downconverter) at the focal point of the dish which is powered.

Power for the LNB is from the satellite receiver which is either from a set-top box or built into the TV.

It's unclear why you're getting a shock off the dish itself, you shouldn't.  It sounds like there is another power injector as indicated in BMitche's answer.  Hunt it down and remove it if needed.